# How to detect overlapping objects in Corona?

Tags: sdk, collision-detection, coronasdk, target, overlapping

What would be the best way to detect that a crosshair is aimed at a **round** target?
I`ve tried adding a small circle in the middle of the crosshair, and detect when that circle and the target collide. But I cant get it to work.

I`ve tried using the x and y coordinates of the target with some luck, but it would be so much better to be able to detect when the crosshair "circle" and the round target are overlapping, and when they are not.

I´ve tried this for overlapping images: http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/flashs-hittestobject-emulated-using-contentbounds but this does not recognize round shapes, only rectangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crosshairs is on the object if the distance from the x,y of the crosshairs to the center of the object is less than or equal to the radius of the object. Pythagoras is your friend here. Check this in `enterFrame` event.

You don't need to do the square root calculation for this, by the way.  Just compute `((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)) + ((y1-y2)*(y1-y2))` each time through `enterFrame`, and compare it to the object's radius squared, which will be constant and can therefore be calculated just once.

Comment: Thanks! I found this when searching for Pythagoras http://www.isk.kth.se/~johanseg/files/prgprj/lesson8.pdf I`ll just have to translate it to Lua ;)

Comment: I think this is the answer. Thanx to you JeffK for pointing out the direction ;) http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/12/12/GameDev-math-recipes-Collision-detection-using-bounding-circles.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog post on non-physics collisions.  Two methods (box overlapping and circle radius ) are covered in it.  I use these in quite a few apps where I don't need physics.

http://omnigeek.robmiracle.com/2011/12/14/collision-detection-without-physics/